# Why do Experimental Design when you could build classifiers?

Tags: machine-learning

Say that you wanted to test whether people who took a placebo were more likely to smoke.

You can devise a experimental design/test for this, but I could also create a model that predicts whether someone will smoke given they took the placebo. If there is high enough correlation, I could determine that the change was significant.

What is the difference between constructing a model vs hypothesis testing?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by 'model'? One tests hypotheses using statistical models (frequently in combination with appropriately designed experiments), so the distinction is not obvious here.

Answer (score 7):

The key aspect of an experimental design is that the participants are randomly assigned to the treatment or the control. That way you can control for potential confounders without having to measure them. In a model you have to hope that all relevant confounders are in your data, and if they are, that they are correctly measured, which is never the case in real data.

Comment: I like both answer's, but I think this is more to the point. If you want a causal model (estimate) then you must rely on (quasi) experiments in some sense, its seldom a question of enough data or a high degree of linear correlation.

Answer (score 5):

> What is the difference between constructing a model vs hypothesis testing?

Like @mkt mentioned - both of these involve models in one for or another so that's a false distinction between them.

#### Differences

As far as I am aware classification is related to separating classes based on some set of common features. It makes a mapping X -> Y where Y is a set of possible classes and X is the feature set.

And hypothesis testing on the other hand is typically concerned with point estimates, without assigning them into some kind of groups. More precisely it tries to estimate the probability to obtain the observed (or a more extreme than observed) point estimate if some null model (called the null hypotheses) is true. And that is called p-value.

#### More on differences

Caltech Professor Yaser Abu-Mostafa in his online course "learning from data" defines these as the key elements for constructing classifiers:

1. There is a patter to "learn".
2. The pattern cannot be written down mathematically.
3. We have data to train on.

The thing is that once we have a concrete null hypothesis in mind the problem becomes mathematical - there is no learning required. We have a null model for generating the data and a procedure to get an estimate. All that has to be done is obtaining p-value from the NULL model. I don't think there is a place for optimization (learning) here.

Of course the estimate itself is "learned" - like taking the mean of data. But it's not part of hypothesis testing itself. For example I can use "accuracy of a classifier" as an estimate and try to construct a p-value for it.

#### Your example

In your example (with real and placebo drugs) you construct a situation that has 2 classes therefore is applicable to classification. But this hides the hypothesis testing scenario. Better think of a hypothesis testing 101: toss a coin 10 times - what is the probability that the coin is fair? I don't see how this can be cast as a question for classification easily.

Or to change your example a bit - what if it was a paired experiment and the test is being done on the same people before and after treatment? It would not be correct to cast "before" group as one class and "after" group as another.

#### More problems

Also your statement:

> If there is high enough correlation, I could determine that the change was significant.

Well - what is high enough? If I have mean difference of 0.5 and a standard deviation of 100 - there will be a lot of overlap. Yet with enough samples hypothesis testing will be able to detect this difference. But what to do in case of classification here? As an example - is 51% accuracy enough to say these are different?

#### Note

All of this is based on some reflection. Hopefully someone will provide a more formal or sourced answer.

Comment: For the coin example, we could construct a classifier to predict whether the coin is fair.

Comment: @sponge_knight by simulating the "training" data from the null (fair) model?

Comment: Yes. Precsiely!!

Comment: But we can get the EXECT answer with simple calculations. Why would we do something more complex that is both harder to interpret and less precise?

Comment: That is what the question asks. These are two different schools of thought.

Comment: Hmm, what school of thought teaches testing the statement about population on sample data by doing classification? Let's try doing one with coin toss as an example: I toss I get 6/10 heads. Then following this classifier strategy I generate random data where the coin is fair. Say I do it 1000 times. I can count the fraction of these 1000 that is above 6/10. I don't see where do I apply the classification in this case? or why? or maybe actually in one view I just did classification and calculated the error rate? IMO that's similar to having a hammer and seeing everything as a nail.

Comment: A classifier could be constructed as: `given ratio of heads/tails, predict whether coin is biased`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42581/discussion-between-karolis-koncevicius-and-sponge-knight).